# How to avoid repeating sed commands when adding sites to Varnish?

Tags: shell-script, sed, performance, for, varnish

This is my script to install Varnish. I run it each time I raise up a new server environment on a VPS.

```
cd ~
apt-get update
apt-get install varnish -y
sed -i 's/Listen 80/Listen 8080/g' /etc/apache2/ports.conf
sed -i 's/\*\:80/\*\:8080/g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
sed -i 's/\*\:80/\*\:8080/g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/domain1.tld.conf && a2ensite domain1.tld.conf
sed -i 's/\*\:80/\*\:8080/g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/domain2.tld.conf && a2ensite domain2.tld.conf
sed -i 's/\*\:80/\*\:8080/g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/domain3.tld.conf && a2ensite domain3.tld.conf
sed -i 's/\*\:80/\*\:8080/g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/domain4.tld.conf && a2ensite domain4.tld.conf
mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/varnish.service.d # Be aware! You might not need this in the future.
cat <<-'VARNISH' > /etc/systemd/system/varnish.service.d/customexec.conf
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/varnishd -j unix,user=vcache -F -a :80 -T localhost:6082 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -S /etc/varnish/secret -s malloc,256m
VARNISH
systemctl restart apache2.service && systemctl daemon-reload && systemctl restart varnish.service
```

This code segment seems quite "heavy", especially the repetitiveness of the sed operations regarding domain.tld.

This get's even "heavier" because I have a code segment which is similar in length that uses to me uninstall varnish and revert all changes just in case of desire.

### My question:

What strategy will you take to make the installation script shorter in general (at least less rows, maybe also less commands), and in particular, to lower amount of sed operations.

### Notes:

- I would assume that the first thing to do is to somehow unify ports.conf, 000-default.conf, and each .conf file of each site, all into one operation. Maybe via a for loop on `/etc/apache2/ports.conf/ && /etc/apache2/sites-available/*/`.

Comment: Besides using a `for ... in` loop for those domains: In your `sed` I would suggest to use `s/\*:80/&80/g`, because then `:` should not be escaped and you can use `&` in the replacement for the whole matched string.

Comment: Hint: you can pass multiple filenames to `sed -i`.

Comment: @Philippos, will you please add explanation why & allows this writing without error?

Comment: @Sparhawk If I do so with 000-default.conf and all other Vhost files it becomes very long so I have to horizontally scroll to get to the end. It's less heavy in rows, but heavy in a row.

Comment: Can you use globs? e.g. `/etc/apache2/sites-available/{000-default,domain{1..4}}.conf`

Comment: Yes. Seems a nice way.

Comment: @Benia From the `sed` man page: "*An <ampersand> ('&') appearing in the replacement shall be replaced by the string matching  the BRE.*"

Comment: @Sparhawk, seems good eh? `/etc/apache2/sites-available/{000-default.conf, *.com.conf}` :)

Comment: What does the `com` part match? Is that a typo? I'd also be wary of using `*` instead of specifying `{1..4}`, just in case there are other files there later. I guess you know your system though. Finally, you can lose 5 characters by putting the `.conf` outside the braces.

Comment: .com uses me to make sure it works only on conf files of websites (with .com tld) instead on file like 000-default.conf, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a function and GNU Parallel you replace the repetetive section:

```
cd ~
apt-get update
apt-get install varnish -y
sed -i 's/Listen 80/Listen 8080/g' /etc/apache2/ports.conf

myfunc() {
    sed -i 's/\*\:80/\*\:8080/g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/$1 && 
      a2ensite $1
}
export -f myfunc

parallel myfunc  {/} ::: /etc/apache2/sites-available/*

mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/varnish.service.d # Be aware! You might not need this in the future.
cat <<-'VARNISH' > /etc/systemd/system/varnish.service.d/customexec.conf
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/varnishd -j unix,user=vcache -F -a :80 -T localhost:6082 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -S /etc/varnish/secret -s malloc,256m
VARNISH
systemctl restart apache2.service && systemctl daemon-reload && systemctl restart varnish.service
```